# How to click a button after redirect?

Tags: javascript

Only for JS testing purposes: I need to go this this [webpage](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form) and click `Create new user` as soon as the page loads . How can I do this  ??

The first step is probably

```
<button onclick="location.href = 'http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form';" id="myButton"  >Go to modal form</button>
```

Now what should I do ? Maybe there is a way to preload the target page and click on the `create new user` using JQuery ?

Comment: Depends on the target page: If you don't control it, you can do that, unless you want it to only work in your browser. In that case you can write a user script or browser extension.

Comment: Do you want to open the model dialog as soon as target page loads then write the code of opening model dialog in documetn.ready(Jquery) or in Javascript you can use window.onload

Answer (score 1):

You can send parameters to control the logic.

Comment: With the assumption that the OP controls the target page.

Comment: +1 Thank you. I updated my question. Could you show me how to do this with that specific webpage

Comment: For example: http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form?type=redirect.
You can use the type parameter in your view to control the logic.